# Explain Linux kernel state terminology e.g. net.next, linux-next, net.git

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, branch, release

I've compiled a few kernels from kernel.org in the past but am unsure of some terminology:

Recently, I had a developer via mailing list tell me to install a specific kernel for a feature, "3.12+ (net.git) should be fine to use." What does the net.git mean? I went to kernel.org and it said 3.12 was mainline (at time of my search) but I didn't see net.git.

If someone says install 3.12 (net.git) how do I obtain it? Does that mean clone from a specific branch on github?

What do terms net.next, linux-next, net.git etc. mean? I imagine there are others too.

Is there a page that documents or can someone explain the meaning of these items in context of the Linux kernel? I'd be interested in knowing others not listed.

I have read https://www.kernel.org/category/faq.html which explains mainline and stable releases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

net.git is David Miller's kernel tree.

You can obtain it like this against your own local tree :

```
git remote add net git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net.git
git fetch net
```

net-next.git is the tree that contains all patches that will be submitted to Linus for Next kernel merge window.

> Is there a page that documents or can someone explain the meaning of these items in context of the Linux kernel?

You can have an overview of all kernel's tree on [kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/)

linux-next in short words is a git tree that is the merge of all of the developer and maintainers trees. You can view all different trees included [here in ./Next/Trees](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/Next/Trees?id=HEAD)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the top-level kernel development happens not on github but on git.kernel.org.

See http://git.kernel.org/ for a list of repositories.

Answer (score 1):

For the linux kernel there are several git trees for every major feature, component or functionality, eg, net, net-next, rdma, devicetree, kvm etc. To get the updates on all trees you can subscribe the mailing list from http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html.

All git trees are maintained by their maintainers and at perticular cycle all the branches pulled to one git tree as an overall kernel tree "linux-kernel-rc-x" and this will be treated as stable kernel after regression testing and can be found at https://www.kernel.org/.
This is how the linux kernel takes contributions from all around the world and is maintained.